# Authenticating docusign via Rails API (Omniauth + Devise) + JS Frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi

I'm trying to create an authentication flow using `Auth Code Grant` where I've added necessary omniauth strategy for Docusign to create `/auth/docusign` routes in Rails API only application.

Here are the steps followed
I'm issuing a request to the route from VueJS client.
`window.open("http://localhost:4000/auth/docusign", "targetWindow", "width=350,height=250")`

After user enters credentials and on successful login I'm calling the callback:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def docusign
    internal_destroy
    @success = false
    userinfo = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    request_info = request.env['omniauth.params'] 
    if userinfo
      info = userinfo.info
      cred = userinfo.credentials
      user = User.find_by(email: info['email']) || User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
      if user
        organization = user.organization
        organization.organization_providers.where(provider_name: 'Docusign').destroy_all
        OrganizationProvider.create(email: info['email'], token_expires_at: Time.at(cred['expires_at']), token_expires_at: Time.now, provider_name: 'Docusign', organization_id: organization.id, token: cred.token)
        @success = true
      end 
    end 
    render 'sessions/docusign'      
  end
end
```

I'd like to pass some params (which I'm accessing in the callback as `request.env['omniauth.params']`) for executing some backend tasks in the method.
When I try `window.open("http://localhost:4000/auth/docusign?email='"+email+"'", "targetWindow", "width=350,height=250")`

It says that the url doesn't match with any redirect urls

I have also tried passing in `redirect_to('/auth/docusign',  query: query)` but on doing so, it doesn't open in a browser due to CORS.

I'm also trying to set it in session cookie, but since it's an API only server, I'm still working towards setting up `cookie store`.

**Question**
Which is the best way to achieve this? To pass some params in the callback and retrieve it.

Then the execution flow continues on the Rails server and the window serves a page with an appropriate response as per authentication status. However during this time, the client window which started the request is not aware of the authentication outcome.

**Question**
How can I communicate to the VueJS client that the authentication process is completed?

**Question**
Am I doing the above flow correctly or are there any better ways to achieve the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to log into your DocuSign Developer Account, Click on Admin and go on the left nav down to "API and Keys" where you can find the integration key you set. Did you set one?
If you did, you should find it and then add the redirectUri to the OAuth settings for that key (client ID in OAuth).
That is why DocuSign login tells you that the redirectURI doesn't match. You can add http://localhost:4000/auth to the list and that should work for your local env.

You cannot past custom variables on the redirectUri, it has to match *exactly* to the one you entered. If you need to pass values to it, there's a way to do that using state.

Here is how the URL should look, notice the `&state=` part of it:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
response_type=code
&scope=YOUR_REQUESTED_SCOPES
&client_id=YOUR_INTEGRATION_KEY
&state=YOUR_CUSTOM_STATE
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
&login_hint=YOUR_LOGIN_HINT
```

You can put whatever you want in there (URI encoded of course) and that value would come back to you when redirected back also with &state= parameter.
This solves the problem and allows you to pass arguments back to your redirect URI.

Comment: I have already added the same and it works fine when I do `window.open("http://localhost:4000/auth/docusign")`.

The error for redirect uri is only coming when I try to add query parameters for the same. For ex: `window.open("http://localhost:4000/auth/docusign?email='"+email+"'")`

Comment: you have to add every variation of the URL, different URL - you have to add it
you cannot use these types of arguments in the redirect. For that you can use the state parameter which will be passed back to you on the redirect

Comment: The url will have dynamic query parameters so not really sure how I will add them to the redirect uris list.  Also state is getting added in the docusign strategy for CSRF,  manipulating the state gives me omniauth error for CSRF detected.

Comment: you cannot add dynamic parameters to a redirectUri for OAuth. There's a solution for this using state parameter.

Comment: If that is the root cause of the issue here, I can write an answer explaining how to use state parameter instead of URL parameter to the redirectUri

Comment: The way that I'm issuing the request, `window.open("http://localhost:4000/auth/docusign?email='"+email+"'")`,I think this is fundamentally incorrect. I need to send the callback the user who is issuing the request from VuejS. I then need to retrieve the same in my  `/auth/docusign/callback` and perform some database operations. After that being done, the new opened browser should notify back to the VueJS app that the callback is completed. 

In this scenario, how can I use the state params to send the information to the callback function?

Comment: The Code launcher examples work but for me somehow, things have got really complicated when I'm trying to do the same with a Rails API app with multiple frontend JS instances running.

Comment: well, Im not sure what other issues you run into. Please explain what error you encounter exactly or write another question.

Comment: So by your answer, instead of calling the rails route, I should call the url directly in the window? And also I believe state should look something like this: `&state="email=someemail,id=someid"`?
I will surely give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: Tried adding state parameter from frontend request:
something like `&state=someemail@email.com` and it gives me the same issue as before:
`csrf_detected | CSRF detected.  OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError`

Comment: this point, OmniAuth-OAuth2 generates the Auth0 authorize url, including a unique state query parameter that it store in the session.
The browser follows the redirect, the user authenticate with Auth0 and Auth0 redirects to your callback url and includes the state that you passed it.
OmniAuth-OAuth2 validates that the state returned in the callback equals what is stored in the session.
https://github.com/auth0/omniauth-auth0/issues/49

Comment: Correct, only way to override state params is in Omniauth Docusign strategy, however that won't be useful in my case

Comment: so, what else can I help you with?

Comment: @InbarGazit can you please look into this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827836/how-to-read-standard-fields-in-the-docusign-api

Comment: I have answered your other question as well. Please mark this one as answered if you don't mind.